# Django - Is get() lazy?

Tags: django, django-models

**Does Django know the number of instances of each model?**

I was wondering... Since Django does not execute the query to the database until the Queryset is evaluated :

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

Then how `MODEL.objects.get(pk=1)`, for example, raises `DoesNotExist` exception when there is no `MODEL` instance with `pk=1`, even if I stored it in a variable without printing it for example?

```
 x = MODEL.objects.get(pk=1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
......
myAPP.models.MODEL.DoesNotExist: MODEL matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `objects.get` is not "lazy" as it does not return a `QuerySet`.

Your code: `MODEL.objects.get(pk=1)` will be evaluated immediately and returned as a model instance rather than a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Ohhhhh, what it said is that **Querysets** are lazy. I don't think that I've read that **get()** is lazy. Thanks :) @Lewis

Comment: @OmarAlHadidi No problem